# Enable touch indicator for iOS app demo video recording

Tags: ios, quicktime, video-capture

I would like to record a demo video of an iOS app with QuickTime on Yosemite. (I found this [tutorial](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/record-iphone-screen-quicktime/)) Is it possible to enable a tap indicator, like a small circle, for touch events so users can easily spot where the author tapped?

Answer (score 46):

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ShowSingleTouches 1
```

[image: single touch]

---

#### How did I find this setting?

Hidden options can be found by running the command below and then, well, figuring out what they do. They are undocumented and can be removed at any time.

```
strings /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator | grep -E '^[A-Z][[:alpha:]]+$'
```

If you can be bothered to go through the garbage add

```
| grep -E '(Enable|Disable|Show|Number)' | sort
```

I got

```
AppleTVRemoteWindowDidShow
EnableKeyboardSync
NSDisabledCharacterPaletteMenuItem
NSDisabledDictationMenuItem
NSScreenNumber
ShowChrome
ShowChromeUIRects
ShowPinchPivotPoint
ShowPinches
ShowSingleTouches
ShowUITestMenu
TouchBarShowRemoteTemplate
```

ShowChrome is Window > Show Device Bezels. ShowChromeUIRects draws some lines around the bezel. The pinch ones are self descriptive. ShowUITestMenu displays a disabled menu in the simulator bar (?). I’ll test TouchBarShowRemoteTemplate when I’m back in my Macbook touch. I don’t know what the others do.

For Xcode the command should be:

```
strings /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit | grep -E '^IDE[[:alpha:]]+$'
```

and the defaults command should carry the prefix com.apple.dt.Xcode. For instance

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexerActivityShowNumericProgress 1
```

ShowSingleTouches is truly useful, but most options are meaningless or just noise. The command above for instance, shows you the number of files that are being indexed, instead a generic progress bar. Thus, just noise.

Comment: "How did I find this setting" +1

Comment: Very nice. I wonder if there is a way to make it show up when doing a screen recording via `xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo`.

Comment: This works for the simulator, but not for a recording of a real device.

Comment: @TravisGriggs try assistive touch for that. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/250290/8668

Comment: Thanks @Jano. I played with that. Not real thrilled with it. It leaves the assistive touch control on all the time, and while apple's tap gesture may be great for indeed assisting people with that gesture, it's not great as a graphic for showing when and where something was touched. I guess I'll try one of the library solutions.

Comment: When recording video with `xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo`, the touches isn't recorded.

Comment: Nice solution. I just wanted to mention that I had to restart the simulator to make the changes take effect.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to demo your own applications (i.e. where you have the actual source code and can make a special demo build), then the best way is to add a helper to your Xcode project, such as https://github.com/toddreed/Touchpose or https://github.com/mapbox/Fingertips. Both overlay your touches with a (customizable) fingerprint indicator when connected to an external mirror (such as when using AirPlay or Quicktime to record).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Fingertips works magically: supports swift, iOS simulator and very simple to install.

Comment: Is there any way using Fingertips to record this output?  Tried sending it to Quicktime on Mac but the visualization of gestures doesn't seem to happen with that setup.

Comment: @RegularExpression Yes. You can set an option on Fingertips `alwaysShowTouches = true`.

Comment: I needed something for C# Xamarin.iOS, and I'm Obj-C illiterate, so I found a Swift implementation https://github.com/LukasCZ/GSTouchesShowingWindow-Swift

Comment: My port of Lukas' GSTouchesShowingWindow-Swift for Xamarin: https://github.com/ColinNg/GSTouchesShowingWindow-Xamarin

Answer (score 7):

The touch events don't get captured on iOS 9 and lower, so you'll need to either set up a camera to capture the taps and present that side by side with the detailed capture or use it to overlay the taps in post production.

This is such a great idea, that I've filed a bug report to officially ask Apple to support this.

- http://openradar.appspot.com/22538143

Comment: I'm using iOS 9.2 and OS X 10 - I don't see the touch events when I record my iPhone demos. You said "don't get captured on iOS 9 and lower" but both my OS's are up to date. What did you mean?

Comment: He is just making this post future proof :)

Comment: P.S.: There's still no way to capture Gestures through Quicktime (iOS 11.3, Mac OS 10.13)

Comment: @JohnnyZ well done! My hedge was only needed for 16 months or so. The [future has come already](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/335038/5472).

Answer (score 4):

If you are building your own app, there are a few libraries that you can use. At the time of posting, here are the 4 iOS libraries I've found ordered by GitHub stars:

1. https://github.com/conopsys/COSTouchVisualizer (Obj-C, 936 stars)
2. https://github.com/mapbox/Fingertips (Obj-C, 724 stars)
3. https://github.com/morizotter/TouchVisualizer (Swift, 638 stars)
4. https://github.com/toddreed/Touchpose (Obj-C, 533 stars)

Comment: And I ported GSTouchesShowingWindow-Swift for Xamarin.iOS: https://github.com/ColinNg/GSTouchesShowingWindow-Xamarin
My bad port is buggy but for short runs it's okay.

Answer (score 4):

Free, portable and effective solution by Kane Cheshire: [ShowTime](https://github.com/KaneCheshire/ShowTime).

Can be added via cocoapods or by including single file into the project. Thanks him for his efforts!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it creating your own tap gesture through Settings > General > Accessibility > AssistiveTouch > CreateNewGesture as it is explained in the following link: [record-iphone-ios-screen-showing-touches-tap-signs](http://www.techgrapple.com/record-iphone-ios-screen-showing-touches-tap-signs/)

Then, select the gesture as a favourite before recording the movie with QuickTime player.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from providing primarily 'link' answers. We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Links can change over time and then we lose the question-answer context. See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review -

Comment: Or you can do it by code adding some of these libraries to your project: [TouchVisualizer](https://github.com/morizotter/TouchVisualizer) or [COSTouchVisualizer](https://github.com/conopsys/COSTouchVisualizer)

Answer (score 2):

You can also touch /AppleInternal on your drive to unlock hidden options in simulator (GUI to some of these hidden defaults)

Might need to boot into recovery to do this on modern OS versions

Comment: Should be noted that this will only work on High Sierra and older.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a solution as well since video conferences are essential nowadays. I am able to add a touch indicator in a real device using a Bluetooth mouse.

I was able to connect my MX Master 2S mouse to an iPad by following this guide: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210546

Answer (score 0):

Just connect a bluetooth mouse to your iphone / ipad.
It works perfectly ! https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210546