# How to remove touch gesture from QuickTime recordings on Mac

Tags: ipod-touch, trackpad, quicktime, multi-touch

At one point I was interested in recording touch gestures using an iPhone Simulator + QuickTtime, so I dutifully followed the advice [in this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/335038/43968) and ran the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ShowSingleTouches 1
```

But now I want to record it without the touch gestures, so I reverse the above command like so:

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ShowSingleTouches 0
```

while this did remove the middle gray circle, there is another black circle with a wider circumference like this:

[image]

I figured this has nothing to do with the iOS Simulator, it's more of a general QuickTime/macOS setting.

How do I remove this touch screen gesture? I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

Comment: Did you try relaunching the simulator?